# can't load_file data in the mysql directory

Tags: mysql, permissions

I'm running as mysql root user on my system.

I can select load_file('/etc/passwd'); no problem

But when I try to select load_file('/var/lib/mysql/mysql'); I get NULL as a result
why? this file is good, I can cat it as root and view the mysql user data, why cant mysql load_file it? Its permissions are the default:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    444 2009-08-04 19:08 user.MYD
```

It's owner is by default the user mysql and has read permission, so why doesn't mysql like to load_file it? Is mysql somehow blocking access to this file and if so how can I bypass that? Doing stuff like `mysql/../mysql` in the path doesn't work, and using hex encoding didn't work either?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `load_file` on a binary .MYD file?

Answer (score 0):

In order for load file to work make sure that all permissions are granted for the MySQL owner and group.

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/foo/*
chmod go+rw /var/lib/mysql/foo/*
```