# mysql load_file from client

Tags: mysql, mysql-loadfile

I want to insert a HTML file, which has lots of SQL meta characters (e.g. single quotes) that I do not want to escape manually, into a MySQL table.

I though I could make the mysql client load file contents into a variable and simply insert that variable, something along these lines:

```
set @result_text = load_file('/tmp/results.html');
INSERT INTO election_results (election_id, result) VALUES (17, @result_text);
```

However, [the documentation of load_file says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file), that it loads the file *on the server*, and not on the client. And that doesn't work for me.

Hence my question: How to make the mysql client load a file into a variable?

NB: [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/load-file-doesnt-work) [do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607486/mysql-load-file-returning-null) [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012445/alternative-to-load-file-function) here, as they mention that load_file works on  the server only. That I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've passed over that Error 1084 by using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/results.html'
INTO TABLE election_results
FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY '\Z'
    ESCAPED BY ''
LINES
    TERMINATED BY ''
(result)
SET election_id = 17
```

please notice the '\Z' as field terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) command, with the `LOCAL` keyword:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/results.html'
    INTO TABLE election_results
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ''
        ESCAPED BY ''
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY ''
    (result)
    SET election_id = 17
```

However, take note of the [Security Issues with `LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data-local.html).

Comment: That gets me  `ERROR 1084 (42000): You can't use fixed rowlength with BLOBs; please use 'fields terminated by'

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly load_file but works fine in my case.

Consider this one-liner (note, I'm on Ubuntu):

```
printf "$(cat update_xml.sql)" "$(cat my.xml | sed s/"'"/"\\\'"/g)" | mysql -h myRemoteHost -u me -p***
```

In update_xml.sql there is:

```
UPDATE
   myTable
SET
   myXmlColumn = '%s'
WHERE
   ...
```